# More efficient way to loop?

Tags: python, performance, for-loop, vectorization, micro-optimization

I have a small piece of code from a much larger script. I figured out that when the function `t_area` is called, it is responsible for most of the run time. I tested the function by itself, and it is not slow, it takes a lot of time because of the number of times that it has to be ran I believe. Here is the code where the function is called:

```
tri_area = np.zeros((numx,numy),dtype=float)
for jj in range(0,numy-1):
    for ii in range(0,numx-1):
      xp = x[ii,jj]
      yp = y[ii,jj]
      zp = surface[ii,jj]
      ap = np.array((xp,yp,zp))

      xp = xp+dx
      zp = surface[ii+1,jj]
      bp = np.array((xp,yp,zp))

      yp = yp+dx
      zp = surface[ii+1,jj+1]
      dp = np.array((xp,yp,zp))

      xp = xp-dx
      zp = surface[ii,jj+1]
      cp = np.array((xp,yp,zp))

      tri_area[ii,jj] = t_area(ap,bp,cp,dp)
```

The size of the arrays in use here are `216 x 217`, and so are the values of `x` and `y`. I am pretty new to python coding, I have used MATLAB in the past. So my question is, is there a way to get around the two for-loops, or a more efficient way to run through this block of code in general? Looking for any help speeding this up! Thanks!

EDIT:

Thanks for the help everyone, this has cleared alot of confusion up. I was asked about the function t_area that is used in the loop, here is the code below:

```
def t_area(a,b,c,d):
ab=b-a
ac=c-a
tri_area_a = 0.5*linalg.norm(np.cross(ab,ac))

db=b-d
dc=c-d
tri_area_d = 0.5*linalg.norm(np.cross(db,dc))

ba=a-b
bd=d-b
tri_area_b = 0.5*linalg.norm(np.cross(ba,bd))

ca=a-c
cd=d-c
tri_area_c = 0.5*linalg.norm(np.cross(ca,cd))

av_area = (tri_area_a + tri_area_b + tri_area_c + tri_area_d)*0.5
return(av_area)
```

Sorry for the confusing notation, at the time it made sense, looking back now I will probably change it. Thanks!

Comment: At a minimum, you don't have to allocate new arrays in every iteration.

Comment: You could save the ~40000 function calls by stocking your `ap,bp,cp,dp` in arrays and rewriting `t_area` to iterate on these arrays. Also, maybe you can do without `np.array` to store only 3 values.

Comment: Can you show us what happens in the function `t_area()`? Is it vectorised?

Comment: The good news is that your function can be fully vectorised. I've edited my answer to take that into account. I've restructured the wording somewhat so that vectorising the problem is at the top. Otherwise, not much has been added.

Comment: Thanks so much! You have given me a better understanding of the python  structure! I have a couple other places in the complete script where this implementation will be very useful! The data that is entered into this script right now is small compared to what will eventually be computed. This array size that I mentioned before is from a ~ 2mb text file, while later on the data from the text file will be  ~ 1.5-2 gb! So this will definitely speed things up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A caveat before we start. `range(0, numy-1)`, which is equal to `range(numy-1)`, produces the numbers from 0 to numy-2, not including numy-1. That's because you have numy-1 values from 0 to numy-2. While MATLAB has 1-based indexing, Python has 0-based, so be a bit careful with your indexing in the transition. Considering you have `tri_area = np.zeros((numx, numy), dtype=float)`, `tri_area[ii,jj]` never accesses the last row or column with the way you have set up your loops. Therefore, I suspect the correct intention was to write `range(numy)`.

Since the fuction `t_area()` is vectorisable, you can do away with the loops completely. Vectorisation means numpy applies some operations on a whole array at the same time by taking care of the loops under the hood, where they will be faster.

First, we stack all the `ap`s for each (i, j) element in a (m, n, 3) array, where (m, n) is the size of `x`. If we take the cross product of two (m, n, 3) arrays, the operation will be applied on the last axis by default. This means that `np.cross(a, b)` will do *for every element (i, j) take the cross product of the 3 numbers in `a[i,j]` and `b[i,j]`*. Similarly, `np.linalg.norm(a, axis=2)` will do *for every element (i, j) calculate the norm of the 3 numbers in `a[i,j]`*. This will also effectively reduce our array to size (m, n). A bit of caution here though, as we need to explicitly state we want this operation done on the 2nd axis.

Note that in the following example my indexing relationship may not correspond to yours. The bare minimum to make this work is for `surface` to have one extra row and column from `x` and `y`.

```
import numpy as np

def _t_area(a, b, c):
    ab = b - a
    ac = c - a
    return 0.5 * np.linalg.norm(np.cross(ab, ac), axis=2)

def t_area(x, y, surface, dx):
    a = np.zeros((x.shape[0], y.shape[0], 3), dtype=float)
    b = np.zeros_like(a)
    c = np.zeros_like(a)
    d = np.zeros_like(a)

    a[...,0] = x
    a[...,1] = y
    a[...,2] = surface[:-1,:-1]

    b[...,0] = x + dx
    b[...,1] = y
    b[...,2] = surface[1:,:-1]

    c[...,0] = x
    c[...,1] = y + dx
    c[...,2] = surface[:-1,1:]

    d[...,0] = bp[...,0]
    d[...,1] = cp[...,1]
    d[...,2] = surface[1:,1:]

    # are you sure you didn't mean 0.25???
    return 0.5 * (_t_area(a, b, c) + _t_area(d, b, c) + _t_area(b, a, d) + _t_area(c, a, d))

nx, ny = 250, 250

dx = np.random.random()
x = np.random.random((nx, ny))
y = np.random.random((nx, ny))
surface = np.random.random((nx+1, ny+1))

tri_area = t_area(x, y, surface, dx)
```

`x` in this example supports the indices 0-249, while `surface` 0-250. `surface[:-1]`, a shorthand for `surface[0:-1]`, will return all rows starting from 0 and up to the last one, but not including it. `-1` serves the same function and `end` in MATLAB. So, `surface[:-1]` will return the rows for indices 0-249. Similarly, `surface[1:]` will return the rows for indices 1-250, which achieves the same as your `surface[ii+1]`.

---

**Note**: I had written this section before it was known that `t_area()` could be fully vectorised. So while what is here is obsolete for the purposes of this answer, I'll leave it as legacy to show what optimisations could have been made had the function not be vectorisable.

Instead of calling the function for each element, which is expensive, you should pass it `x`, `y,`, `surface` and `dx` and iterate internally. That means only one function call and less overhead.

Furthermore, you shouldn't create an array for `ap`, `bp`, `cp` and `dp` every loop, which again, adds overhead. Allocate them once outside the loop and just update their values.

One final change should be the order of loops. Numpy arrays are row major by default (while MATLAB is column major), so `ii` performs better as the outer loop. You wouldn't notice the difference for arrays of your size, but hey, why not?

Overall, the modified function should look like this.

```
def t_area(x, y, surface, dx):
    # I assume numx == x.shape[0]. If not, pass it as an extra argument.
    tri_area = np.zeros(x.shape, dtype=float)

    ap = np.zeros((3,), dtype=float)
    bp = np.zeros_like(ap)
    cp = np.zeros_like(ap)
    dp = np.zeros_like(ap)

    for ii in range(x.shape[0]-1): # do you really want range(numx-1) or just range(numx)?
        for jj in range(x.shape[1]-1):
            xp = x[ii,jj]
            yp = y[ii,jj]
            zp = surface[ii,jj]
            ap[:] = (xp, yp, zp)

            # get `bp`, `cp` and `dp` in a similar manner and compute `tri_area[ii,jj]`
```