# Indexing and vectorizing a nested-loop

Tags: python, performance, multidimensional-array, vectorization, nested-loops

I am running a particular script that will calculate the fractal dimension of the input data. While the script does run fine, it is very slow, and a look into it using `cProfile` showed that the function `boxcount` is accounting for around 90% of the  run time. I have had similar issues in a previous questions,[More efficient way to loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34701570/more-efficient-way-to-loop), and   [Vectorization of a nested for-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34817500/vectorization-of-a-nested-for-loop). While looking at cProfile, the function itself does not run slow, but in the script is needs to be called a large number of times. I'm struggling to find a way to re-write this to eliminate the large number of function calls. Here is the code below:

```
 for j in range(starty, endy):
        jmin=j-half_tile
        jmax=j+half_tile+1

    #   Loop over columns

        for i in range(startx, endx):
            imin=i-half_tile
            imax=i+half_tile+1

    #   Extract a subset of points from the input grid, centered on the current
    #   point. The size of tile is given by the current entry of the tile list.

            z = surface[imin:imax, jmin:jmax]
    #       print 'Tile created. Size:', z.shape

    #   Calculate fractal dimension of the tile using 3D box-counting

            fd, intercept = boxcount(z,dx,nside,cell,slice_size,box_size)
            FractalDim[i,j] = fd
            Lacunarity[i,j] = intercept
```

My real problem is that for each loop through `i,j`, it finds the values of `imin,imax,jmin,jmax`, which is basically creating a subset of the input data, centered around the values of `imin,imax,jmin,jmax`. The function of interest, `boxcount` is evaluated over the range of `imin,imax,jmin,jmax` as well. For this example, the value of `half_tile` is `6`, and the values for `starty,endy,startx,endx` are `6,271,5,210` respectively. The values of `dx,cell,nside,slice_size,box_size` are all just constants used in the `boxcount` function.

I have done problems similar to this, just not with the added complication of centering the slice of data around a particular point. Can this be vectorized? or improved at all?

**EDIT**

Here is the code for the function `boxcount` as requested.

```
def boxcount(z,dx,nside,cell,slice_size,box_size):
    # fractal dimension calculation using box-counting method

    n = 5 # number of graph points for simple linear regression
    gx = [] # x coordinates of graph points
    gy = [] # y coordinates of graph points


    boxCount = np.zeros((5)) 
    cell_set = np.reshape(np.zeros((5*(nside**3))), (nside**3,5))

    nslice=nside**2

# Box is centered at the mid-point of the tile. Calculate for each point in the
# tile, which voxel the contains the point

    z0 = z[nside/2,nside/2]-dx*nside/2

    for j in range(1,13):
        for i in range(1,13):
            ij = (j-1)*12 + i
#            print 'i, j:', i, j

            delz1 = z[i-1,j-1]-z0
            delz2 = z[i-1,j]-z0
            delz3 = z[i,j-1]-z0
            delz4 = z[i,j]-z0
            delz = 0.25*(delz1+delz2+delz3+delz4)

            if delz < 0.0:
                break
            slice = ceil(delz)
#            print " delz:",delz," slice:",slice

            # Identify the voxel occupied by current point
            ijk = int(slice-1.)*nslice + (j-1)*nside + i

            for k in range(5):
                if cell_set[cell[ijk,k],k] != 1:
                   cell_set[cell[ijk,k],k] = 1

#   Set any cells deeper than this one equal to one aswell
#                   index = cell[ijk,k]
#                   for l in range(int(index),box_size[k],slice_size[k]):
#                       cell_set[l,k] = 1

# Count number of filled boxes for each box size
    boxCount = np.sum(cell_set,axis=0)
#   print "boxCount:", boxCount

    for ib in range(1,n+1):
#       print "ib:",ib," x(ib):",math.log(1.0/ib),"  y(ib):",math.log(boxCount[ib-1])
        gx.append( math.log(1.0/ib) )
        gy.append( math.log(boxCount[ib-1]) )

# simple linear regression
    m, b = np.polyfit(gx,gy,1)
#   print "Polyfit: Slope:", m,' Intercept:', b
#   fd = m-1
    fd = max(2.,m)
    return(fd,b)
```

Comment: Move the iterative argument computations into `boxcount()` and make it a generator of multiple results.

Comment: I actually tried that before posting on here, for whatever reason, it takes multiple times longer for the script to run with the interables from the above code within the function `boxcount` If there is a way to calculate z, and plug that into `boxcount`, then that would solve my issues I think.

Comment: If you profiled that version of the program, you would know if calculating `z` in `boxcount()` would help. It's unclear what `surface` is exactly, since that's not how a two dimensional array could be indexed in Python (or a dictionary for that matter) — perhaps that is what you should optimize because it looks like a custom class of some sort.

Comment: Can you share boxcount content? so that we can help you vectorizing the full content?